# How to make a query with relations and order it by date of the relation in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have the User model, I also have the Post model.

I would like to get 4 users through the newest posts of my entire Post model (taking into account that even a single user could have n number of newest posts) and then get the posts of each user (two for each user) obtained through of the relationship, something like that in case it is not understood very well

[image]

I have no problem getting the relationship from the blade, but what I can't get are the 4 users with the newest posts

`User` model

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

`Post` model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

This is the query I was doing, but this will simply return any 4 users (I guess by their id) and each user with their 2 newest posts, which is not what I need

```
User::query()
    ->whereHas('posts', function ($query){
        $query->where('state', PostStateEnum::PUBLISHED)
            ->orderBy('updated_at')
            ->take(2);
    })
    ->take(4)
    ->get();
```

ADD:

I have tried with join() but I get the same user

My code:

```
        return User::query()
        ->join('posts', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('posts.state', '=', PostStateEnum::PUBLISHED)
        ->orderByDesc('posts.updated_at')
        ->select('users.*')
        ->with('posts', function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', PostStateEnum::PUBLISHED)
                ->orderByDesc('updated_at')
                ->take(2)
                ->get();
        })
        ->take(4)
        ->get();
```

that return 4 users, but all are the same user

Comment: If you want to sort by a different table's column, you need to use a `join()` statement. `has()` and `whereHas()` performs filtering, but doesn't do any kind of join logic, which is required to do `ORDER BY table.column` in SQL.

Comment: what if the user only has one post?

Comment: I would perhaps get posts that are distinct user_id, sorted by post creation and then limit  4. Then query those users and get their posts.  You would need a package to limit the children to two posts staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [subquery ordering](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#subquery-ordering)

```
public function getUsersByNewerPosts()
{
    return User::query()
        ->whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', PostStateEnum::PUBLISHED);
        })
        ->orderByDesc(
            Post::select('updated_at')
                ->whereColumn('user_id', 'users.id')
                ->where('state', PostStateEnum::PUBLISHED)
                ->orderByDesc('updated_at')
                ->limit(1)
        )
        ->take(4)
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: subquery has O(n2) time complexity how can it be the best way?, join is the better choice

Comment: @bhucho I updated my question, I have tried with join but I get an array of 4 users, but that users are the same user

Comment: use leftJoin and then only select the column of the table with which you want to orderBy then you can simply write `->orderBy('posts.updated_at', "DESC");`if not understood I will write this in answer below

Comment: also use any one of them you can avoid using both relation and join if you are getting join then you can use that, I know it looks like more raw method than using eloquent but relationships work differently than join logic so orderBy for relations becomes quite indirect

Comment: @bhucho I tried using leftJoin and select only posts.updated_at but I get only the updated_at column data. only if I select users.* I have the user data, I'm a bit confused but thankful for the help so far, it's helped me quite a bit, could you help me a bit more specifically?

Comment: If you are willing to use leftJoin then you can use posts.* and avoid using any relationship, I suggested to use posts.updated_at to only get updated at column as I thought you are bound to use relationships